Unable to send images to spring boot backend from react native mobile app

I am trying to send api request with image as one of param to spring boot backend from react native mobile app, but recieving null value in image param in backend
But when i send same api request from postman, i can see image in backend

export const createGroupApiAction = async (
  createGroupRequestDTO: CreateGroupRequestDTO,
  token: string
): Promise<Group> => {
  // Create a FormData object to handle the file and text data
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('userId', createGroupRequestDTO.userId);
  formData.append('userName', createGroupRequestDTO.userName);
  formData.append('groupName', createGroupRequestDTO.groupName);
  formData.append('groupDescription', createGroupRequestDTO.groupDescription);
  formData.append('isPublic', createGroupRequestDTO.isPublic.toString());
  formData.append('isPaid', createGroupRequestDTO.isPaid.toString());
  formData.append('price', createGroupRequestDTO.price?.toString() || '');

  // If there's an image, convert the image URI to a blob and append it
  if (createGroupRequestDTO.groupImage) {
    const groupImageBlob = await uriToBlob(createGroupRequestDTO.groupImage.uri);
    formData.append('bannerImage', groupImageBlob, 'group-image.png'); // Name and type of the file
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${groupBaseUrl}/create`, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });

    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('API request failed: ' + error.message);
  }
};

// Helper function to convert image URI to Blob
const uriToBlob = async (uri: string): Promise<Blob> => {
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return new File([blob], 'group-image.png', { type: blob.type });
};

Spring boot
  @PostMapping(value = GroupEndPoints.GroupCrud.CREATE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<NewGroupCreationResponseDTO> createGroup(
            @RequestParam("groupName") String groupName,
            @RequestParam("userId") String userId,
            @RequestParam("userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam("groupDescription") String groupDescription,
            @RequestParam("isPublic", required = false) boolean isPublic,
            @RequestParam("isPaid", required = false) boolean isPaid,
            @RequestParam(value = "price", required = false) Double price,
            @RequestPart(name  = "bannerImage", required = false) MultipartFile bannerImage 
    ) {
        log.info("{} API hit", GroupEndPoints.Base_URL + GroupEndPoints.GroupCrud.CREATE);
}


Basicially i put debugger point on log.info() , and checked and i could see 'bannerImage' as null although i had send image from react native side
But when i send same data to backend from postman i can see 'bannerImage' in backend

tried to send request to backend from postman and it worked
curl --location 'http://localhost:9090/aphrodite/auth/group/create' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
--form 'groupName="\"pritam 4\""' \
--form 'bannerImage=@"/C:/Users/Pritam/Downloads/Screenshot 2024-10-17 173738.png"' \
--form 'userId="abc"' \
--form 'userName="ad"' \
--form 'groupDescription="sw"'


**I have also added this spring boot configuration **

 @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }


If you use fetch(uri), due to Android and iOS access rule, the image may not be reachable in the next time you try to access the uri. So please only use it in case you want to convert uri to base64 string
Btw, just convert blob like this is okay:
const groupImageBlob = {
          uri: createGroupRequestDTO.groupImage.uri
          type: image.mime, // image/png => should be dynamic for other image path
          name: 'group-image.png',
        }

formData.append('bannerImage', groupImageBlob);

